# Como trocar informações entre classes?

Tags: android

Quero passar informações de uma classe para outra por exemplo:

```
TextView t;
```

Tenho um TextView aqui, chamado t e ele está na classe Main.

Agora na classe Main2:

```
t.setText("TextView saiu da Main para a Main2");
```

Eu ja tentei colocar `public` mas ainda fala que a variavel `t` não é existente na Main2.

Comment: Já tentou colocar na declaração do f: `public static float f = 3.5;`?

Comment: Sim já tentei obrigado

Comment: Gutie, estou revertendo as edições aqui. Vamos focar no problema dos floats na outra pergunta ok? Por favor edite a outra focando nesse problema.

Comment: Olha meu codigo @bfavaretto veja o que você pode fazer:
https://github.com/AndroidComunite/Android-Error/tree/master

Comment: @Gutie Quem tem de fazer é você... Lá na outra pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Para acessar uma variável de outra classe, basta indicar que a variável é `estática`, o que permitirá acessá-la sem a necessidade de um objeto:

```
public static TextView t;
```

Para acessar de outra classe, deve-se indicar também a classe na qual a variável existe:

```
Main.t.setText("TextView saiu da Main para a Main2");
```

exemplo:

```
public class Example{
    public static TextView t;
}
public class Example2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example.t.setText("TextView saiu da Main para a Main2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Posso te sugerir 3 opções

**1 Opção**

Usar singleton, ou simplesmente definir uma classe  como static.

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null)
            uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
        return uniqueInstance;
    }
}
```

Leia mais em: Padrão de Projeto Singleton em Java http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-singleton-em-java/26392#ixzz3FfAWD3Il

**2 opção**

Definir variaveis ou objetos globais, você pode criar uma class Aplication no Android e definir variaveis globais ou até mesmo o singleton.

[Exemplo](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/).

**3 Opção**

Você pode passar variaveis ou objetos por Intent para outras activitys ou fragments

**Activity 1**

```
Intent i=new Intent("....");
i.putExtra("TEXT", "Olá");
startActivity(i);
```

**Activity 2**

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String var_intent = bundle.getString("TEXT");
text .setText(var_intent );
```

[Leia mais.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o seguinte código abaixo:

**Classe Main1:**

```
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main1 {

    private TextView t;

    public TextView getT() {
        return t;
    }

}
```

**Classe Main2:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2 extends Activity {

    private TextView t;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Main1 objeto = new Main1();
        t = objeto.getT();
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); //aqui você põem o nome do id do textView
        t.setText("TextView saiu da Main para a Main2");

    }

}
```

Comment: A instancia da classe é local, nao ira funcionar a não ser que seja static. e seu acesso também.