# Como trocar o valor de variaveis entre Activitys?

Tags: android

Eu tenho três Classes :

```
Main1
Main2
Main3
```

Agora dentro da `Main1` tenho um `float`:

```
static float f = 3.5;
```

E dentro da `Main2` tenho um `TextView`:

```
public static TextView tv;
```

E na `Main3` quero colocar :

```
  Main2.tv. setText("O valor do float f é " + Main1.f);
```

Eu tentei utilizar os codigos que me apresentaram na "duplicata", mas nenhum me esclareceu, e nem ajudou a resolver meus problemas.
E as respostas que eles me passaram eu não sei por que não estavam funcionando, pois estou com duvida nessa parte, e o que eles me passaram, trocavam informações entre classes de uma mesma Activity.

Comment: Eu respondi, mas assim como tens funciona.

Comment: Qual é a diferença desta para essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35336/como-trocar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-entre-classes?

Comment: Nenhuma @bigown, é para fechar...

Comment: É pq tudo que tinha naquela não conseguiu resolver meu problema ...

Comment: E agora eu acrescentei o float

Comment: Guti mas que problema é que tens em concreto?

Comment: @Gutie Em teoria, as respostas à sua pergunta anterior respondem a esta também. Se não está funcionando, favor [edit] esta pergunta explicando melhor o que está dando errado. A edição que você fez na outra pergunta invalidou as respostas que já existiam (inclusive uma que estava aceita), então pretendemos revertê-la em breve. Para mais detalhes, participe da [discussão do caso no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2128).

Comment: @bfavaretto eu tentei utilizar os codigos que eles me passaram na duplicata porém, me passaram apenas de classes,
e eu quero de Activitys(telas) ...

Comment: @Gutie parece-me que você ainda não entendeu o que queremos... Para ajudá-lo, precisaríamos que você explicasse o **por quê** da solução anterior não resolver seu problema... Quando você tenta, é acusado algum erro? Tem como colocar a parte do código que está dando problema?

Comment: @Gutie em Android a forma de passar entre Ativity's é a que te responderam na duplicata. Ou por referência com o `static` ou por `Intent` com o `putExtra`. Se tiver algum erro em concreto que lhe apareça edite esta pergunta e coloque-o ai

Comment: @Gammeth o problema esta aqui...
`Main2.tv. setText("O valor do float f é " + Main1.f);`

Comment: E até ai não sei a razão..

Comment: @Gutie Ele não imprime nenhum tipo de erro para você??

Comment: `10-14 17:52:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(2779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 17:52:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(2779): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 17:52:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):  at com.gustavo.sample.Count$2.onClick(Count.java:39)
10-14 17:52:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-14 17:52:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-14 17:52:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)`
@Gammeth

Comment: Aqui está meu codigo para quem quiser olhar:
https://github.com/AndroidComunite/Android-Error/tree/master

Comment: @Gutie a ideia de colocar o erro na pergunta, é editando ela e colocando nela esses dados... Além disso, ninguém vai debugar pra você todo o seu projeto... Uma ideia do que você pode fazer é tentar ir debugando devagar... Tente armazenar em variáveis temporárias do tipo: `float fl = Main1.f; TextView text = Main2.tv;` e ver se eles realmente foram inicializadas...

Comment: Blz vou tentar debugar parte por parte,brigadão

Comment: @Gammeth eu debuguei e o erro é quando eu tento colocar algo do tipo:
`Main3.text.setText("Valor " + MainActivity.fl);`